# Common trigger for all sObject

Tags: trigger

We have requirement that we need to call a common class if any update happens in 10 of sObjects. As per the current solution we have to write 10 trigger and each trigger will call the common class. is their any other solution that we can have like a common trigger or common action handler for all the 10 sObjects. Please guide me with some solution on this issue.

Comment: What you have stated is the only option in terms of Apex triggers; ensure you have written your logic in a separate Apex Trigger Handler class that deals with SObject and add the *n* triggers that (instantiate and) invoke this handler.

Answer (score 1):

No, a trigger can only be placed on one object, so you do need the 10 triggers. The point of the trigger handler class is indeed to minimize the amount of logic you need to duplicate, but you can't do so using just a single trigger.